# CAsyncSocket::Create fails in CWinThread::Initinstance but works in Constructor

Tags: c++, mfc

I have CAsynSocket derived class in my CWinThread derived class

I use new and create actually create suspended
To create the CWinThread

In my CWINTHREAD::Initintance

I try to do a CAsyncsocket::Create the program goes "south" the code totally leaves initinstance
When I move the code to the CWINTHREAD 
Constructor it works

I'm baffeled

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Why are you trying to open a socket connection from a UI thread?

Comment: I would like to do send and receive via message queue and UI has a message pump regardless it should work,

Comment: I would like to do send and receive via messages and UI has a message pump regardless it should work I just moved the code back to Initnstance and put a _try {} and catch{} around the CAsyncSocket::create as by the wild branch after create I was sure there was an exception but the catch didn't pick it up

Comment: As I said I get messages from other windows to do do send or receive and a UI has message pump not at home right now but I'll post my code tommorow BTW is there a way to configure stack overflow to send e-mail notification when someone replies thanks

Comment: for (i = 0, start_port = 11007; i < 4; start_port++, i++)
           {

Comment: Here is the code I have a loop in the CWinApp::Initinstance                   for (i = 0, start_port = 11007; i < 4; start_port++, i++)
           { threadptr[i] = new SockCLeintThread(start_port);                      ret = threadptr[i]->CreateThread (CREATE_SUSPENDED);                    In SockCLientThread::initinstance
              if(thisocket.Create(thisocket.port,SOCK_STREAM,(FD_READ | FD_WRITE | FD_OOB | FD_ACCEPT | FD_CONNECT | FD_CLOSE),ipaddr)== 0)
          {
                          error_code =  thisocket.GetLastError();
                   }

Comment: I am sorry for how I posted the code the "Add a comment" has a limited amount of characters "thisocket" is a protected member of   SockClientThread